# First time using an iPhone

Tags: iphone, icloud, gmail

This is the first time using an iPhone!

I used to own a Samsung Galaxy starting with the 5.5.1, S2, Note 2, S4, S5, etc...so I'm defently not used to this iPhone! With the Samsung's I used the Google Play store & or Market, or the Galaxy Apps store to download my music, apps, & games.

- Can the Google play store be downloaded on the iPhone with my Google account? If not how do I download games & apps & what do I use to do it?
- Do I have to have an iCloud account or iTunes account?
- Can I use my Gmail/email account or do I need to have a Apple email account?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Ask Different works better if you ask only one question per post, you can always ask several questions in different posts if needed.

Answer (score 3):

1. Can the Google play store be downloaded on the iPhone with my Google
   account?
   **Answer:** No you can't download Play Store in any Apple device.
2. If not how do I download games & apps & what do I use to
   do it?
   **Answer:** You can't access your Google Play purchases, so you will need to use App Store to purchase/download again any app you want, iTunes app to purchase music, iBooks app to purchase books...
3. Do I have to have an iCloud account or iTunes account? 
   **Answer:** You have an Apple Id and you will use that to log in into iTunes and iCloud, you have some 5GB free storage, if you want more you need to pay.
4. Can I use my Gmail/email account or do I need to have a Apple
   email account?
   **Answer:** You can download Gmail app from App Store, you don't need to use Apple accounts, although you get one when creating your Apple Id account.

Finally, you can easily get step by step tutorials for any of this topics if you search in Google like How to... setup iCloud Account, create an Apple Id, etc

Answer (score 1):

1. No you cannot download the Play store on your iPhone. All Apps and Games are downloaded/bought through the App Store. Music, Movies and TV Shows are downloaded/bought through the iTunes Store.
2. You need an [Apple ID](https://appleid.apple.com/) to get access to the App Store and iTunes Store.
3. You can use your Gmail account to create an [Apple ID](https://appleid.apple.com/). And yes you can add Gmail to the Mail app via Settings > Mail.

   However, I strongly advice you to get an iCloud account and use that as your Apple ID. iCloud give some advantages to your iPhone. Like backups, synchronisation, Find my iPhone (in case you lose your device).